# How to create an hexa randomly numbers in python?

Tags: python, random

I want to create a file of hexadecimal number where everyone is composed of 32 elements like this:

```
ccddeeff8899aabb4455667fffffff33
e0370734313198a2885a308aaaaaaaa8
7354776f204f6e65204e696bbbbbbb6f
64976fbb4f6e6ee0cc681e6ccccccc77
```

I try by this code to create my numbers but I don't now how to have 32 elements for each number:

```
   import random
   Plaintext_file = open("C:\\Users\\user\\Plaintexts.txt", "w")
   for i in range(5):
      i = random.randint(0, 16777215)
      print "%x" % i 
      Plaintext_file.write("%x \n" % i)
```

The result that I have:

```
c39ea9
a737a0
d2d352
fcebf1
ade761
```

I would be very grateful if you could help.

Comment: where does 16777215 come from? It's not 16**32.

Comment: i = random.randint(0, 16**32) Doesn't give me  32 elements, sometimes it gives me 31 elements

Comment: because the first digit is zero 1/16 of the time. (use `"%032x"` to force width to be 32 with zero padding).

Comment: No I am sorry It doesn't work

Comment: I still have the same  problem

Comment: `"%032x" % random.randrange(16**32)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4().hex
'd734fde6d45e47e99d06f129b5c128f8'
```

Comment: It works but I need to return back to line, Plaintext_file.write("\n" % i)this one doesn't work

Comment: Plaintext_file.write("%s\n" % uuid.uuid4().hex)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`binascii.b2a_hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_uu) to convert binary data to a line of ASCII characters,

```
>>> import os,binascii
>>> binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(16))
'a8922d48fba3bddd0214a338ce090ea6'
```

[`os.urandom(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) returns a string of `n` random bytes from an OS-specific randomness source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.choice` using the list of accepted hex chars (from `string.hexdigits` ):

```
>>> import string
>>> string.hexdigits
'0123456789abcdefABCDEF'
>>> import random
>>> "".join([random.choice(string.hexdigits) for x in range(32)])
'37bAA921dd6BE09eEff45c280D62FFAb'
```

If you want only the lowercase you case use `string.hexdigits[:16]`:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.hexdigits[:16]
'0123456789abcdef'
>>> import random
>>> "".join([random.choice(string.hexdigits[:16]) for x in range(32)])
'805cb6c9b38515b588bfec42613eff9d'
```

Comment: @nani92, did you check this code? I'm not so sure what/where exactly is the problem.

Comment: Using '0123456789abcdefABCDEF' increases the chances of picking a hex digit in the range a..f.  It might be better to use '01234567890123456789abcdefABCDEF' if case is significant in the result.